# perl script to compare an array lines and print the line if first and third string in the line is matching

Tags: perl

I have an array `@array1` containing these lines.

```
QA.15|foo123|P101|SR234 2345
QA.15|foo124|P102|SR236 2234
QA.15|foo125|P103|SR234 2235
QA.15|foo123|P102|SR235 2322    
QA.15|foo123|P103|SR234 2341
```

I have split `@array1` using `[\\||\s+]` as a delimiter, and the resulting `@array2` is:

```
QA.15 foo123 P101 SR234 2345 ==> Matched
QA.15 foo124 P102 SR236 2234
QA.15 foo125 P103 SR234 2235
QA.15 foo123 P102 SR235 2322
QA.15 foo123 P103 SR234 2341 ==> Matched
```

I need an output such that, first and third string of the line must be matched against each array lines and matched lines must be captured or printed out.

**Expected output**

```
QA.15 foo123 P101 SR234 2345 
QA.15 foo123 P103 SR234 2341
```

Below code is what I am trying to get the result which isnt working.

```
my $file = "data.file";
my @array1 = `cat $file | grep -i 'P80*'`;
my @array2; 
foreach my $line (@array1)
{ 
    my @split = split /\|/, $line;
    push @array2, @split;
}
my @matched_lines;
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#array1; $i++)
{
    foreach (@array2)
    { 
        if ($array2[1] && $array2[3] =~ m/$array1[$i++]/)
        { 
            push @matched_lines, $array1[$i];
        }
    }
 }

 print "@matched_lines\n";
```

Comment: ... and what's the problem you're having with your code?

Comment: Yes, what have you tried?

Comment: Thanks Sobrique & Jcaron,

Comment: @jcaron,, this is what I have tried with no help.                           #!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my $file = "data.file";
my @array1 = `cat $file | grep -i 'P80*'`;
my @array2;
foreach my $line (@array1)
{
        my @split = split /\|/, $line;
        push @array2, @split;
}
my @matched_lines;
for (my $i = 0; $i <= $#array1; $i++)
{
        foreach (@array2)
        {
                if ($array2[1] && $array2[3] =~ m/$array1[$i++]/)
                {
                push @matched_lines, $array1[$i];
                }
        }
}
print "@matched_lines\n";

Comment: @Jcaron, All I am trying is perl script that goes through the array line by line and compares each line with the previous line (or next line) to look for matching values in the first & Third columns. Then I would like to print the lines which matched first and third columns.

Comment: You `grep P80` in the file, but there is no P80 ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some remarks about the current program, first.

- The initial grep greps 'P80' and there is none in the sample above (changed to P10 below)
- The split did not have space as delimiter
- In Perl you have to push a reference to an array, to make an array of arrays
- Algo is O(n<sup>2</sup>)

A slightly different approach:

Creation of a hash which key is `$split[1].'|'.$split[3]` (since `|` is not in the data anymore). The hash value is an array of indexes in `@array1` (the lines) having the same key, ie, matching.

Finally, for each value of the `%match` hash which is an array of at least 2 elements (indexes in @array1), print the corresponding lines (@array1).

```
my $file = "data.file";
my @array1 = `cat $file | grep -i 'P10'`;

my %match = ();

# make a hash of array of @array1 indexes based on [1]|[3] key
for my $i (0 .. $#array1) {
    chomp $array1[$i];
    @split = split /[\|\s]+/, $array1[$i];
    $key = $split[1] . '|' . $split[3];
    $match{$key} = [] if ( ! exists($match{$key}));
    push @{$match{$key}}, $i;
}

# go over %match and print entries with at least 2 indexes
foreach my $key ( keys %match ) {
    if ($#{$match{$key}} >= 1) {
       print "Next are matching:\n";
       for $i (0 .. $#{$match{$key}}) {
          print $array1[ ${$match{$key}}[$i] ] . "\n";
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Bunch of Thanks to you, your code works like charm for me :)

Comment: with your code I was able to implement and make use of it for different kind of data structures with different value with same logic of yours, but ultimately I am stuck at getting final output out of matched contents, I tried out multiple ways with no help, if you could advice me on how to get below requirement working, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: After getting matched contents, my output is as follows.

Comment: QA.15|foo123|P102|SR234 2345
QA.15|foo124|P104|SR236 3234
QA.15|foo125|P102|SR234 2235
QA.15|foo123|P104|SR235 4322    
QA.15|foo123|P102|SR234 2341
QA.15|foo123|P104|SR234 5345
QA.15|foo124|P103|SR236 3234
QA.15|foo125|P104|SR234 6235
QA.15|foo123|P103|SR235 4322    
QA.15|foo123|P104|SR234 7341
QA.15|foo123|P104|SR234 5341
QA.15|foo123|P104|SR234 7432
QA.15|foo123|P104|SR234 6543
QA.15|foo123|P104|SR234 8765

I have an array (@matched_arr) consisting value in above format|pattern in about more than 20000 lines.

Comment: each two lines comes with three combination within an array as follows.
1. P102 & P104.
2. P103 & P104.
3. P104 alone.

For first scenario I need to do P103 = P104 - P102, value for P104 & P102 is last value of each line, eg (3234 - 2345) for EG: first two lines of @matched_arr. and then the first line (QA.15|foo123|P102|SR234 2345) will become (QA.15|foo123|P103|SR234 889) & next line with P104 remains the same

Comment: For Second scenario it is P102 = P104 - P103, and lines consisting P103 (QA.15|foo124|P103|SR236 3234) becomes (QA.15|foo124|P102|SR236 3001) and the next line with P104 remains as it is.

Third scenario is line P104 not in combination with either P102 or P103, it just continues with P104 lines, as shown in my  array lines at the bottom, that needs to be left as it is.

I only require a logic to process above three scenarios, calculation and replacement of P* values I can take acre of.